# How to read special characters like "ó" in Excel with TCL?

Tags: excel, tcl, ascii

There are some special characters in my .xls file. I am trying to read all lines in .xls and write them into .txt file, but characters are changed. For example: There are `ó`s in the Excel. 
TCL Script:

```
set Channel_Read [open Sample.xls r]
set Channel_Write [open Text.txt a+]
while {[gets $Channel_Read Line]>=0} {
puts $Channel_Write $Line
}
close $Channel_Write
close $Channel_Read
```

After I open Text.txt, `ó` is changed to `\&\#243;`.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: You can't read a .xls file line-by-line with `gets`. It's a proprietary binary format - you need a special parser.

Comment: You might be interested into [this gitrepo](https://github.com/willblatt/excelScl). I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate points:

1. The .xls format is binary, so you should use:

   ```
   set Channel_Read [open "Sample.xls" rb]
   ```

   (Or `fconfigure $Channel_Read -translation binary` straight after opening; it's equivalent.)

   Similarly, if you're dumping it to another file, using `a+b` as the open mode for that — for the same sorts of reasons — will stop output mangling.
2. For a straight copy from one channel to another, use `fcopy` instead of a loop. The `fcopy` command uses some low-level tricks to do things more efficiently.

   ```
   fcopy $Channel_Read $Channel_Write
   ```

However, I really suspect that something is going on other than is directly revealed in the information that you provide. Tcl wouldn't mangle bytes in the way you describe (I know what the encoding engine is doing, and it doesn't work that way for any encoding). What's more, the concept of a “line” in relation to a spreadsheet is distinctly off; spreadsheets don't have lines, they have rows (and columns, and sheets) and they don't need to be arranged in the same way at all. I also fail to see why appending a binary spreadsheet to another file would be a good thing to do.

I think you need to stop, think about the wider task that you are trying to do, and then try to solve that rather than just this little piece. While I could answer your immediate questions in more depth, I suspect that I'd not be giving you *genuinely helpful* assistance if I did.

Comment: For all I know, `\&\#243;` is how Excel internally represents an `ó`…

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Use the [TCOM](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/tcom/tcom.n.html) package, which is designed for exactly what you're trying to do. Here are some examples: [Tcom examples for Microsoft Excel](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11900)